Classify all open affine subschemes of a projective variety
Currently I am pondering a question from algebraic geometry that can be stated in very simple terms: Let $X \subseteq P^n_k$ be a projective variety, subscheme of projective $n$-space over an algebraically closed field $k$. Now classify all open affine subsets $U \subseteq X$.
As a first step one could consider the closed subscheme $Y = X - U$ and its (co)dimension or whether it is irreducible or not to get a first distinguishing invariant.
If one now considers the Hilbert scheme $H = H_{X|k}$ of all closed subschemes $Y \subseteq X$ one could ask for a characterization of all closed points $z$ of $H$ whose corresponding $Y_z \subseteq X$ has affine complement $U_z = X - Y_z$.
By Serre's criterion these are the $U = U_z$ for which $H^1(U, F) = 0$ for each coherent sheaf $F$ on $U$ or, because a coherent sheaf $F$ on $U$ is always the restriction of a coherent $F'$ on $X$ also the $U = U_z$ for which $H^1(U,F|_U) = 0$ for all $F$ coherent on $X$.
So one could attempt making a start by fixing a certain coherent sheaf $F$ on $X$ and classify or enumerate all open $U = U_z \subseteq X$ such that $H^1(U,F|_U) = 0$.
What can be said about these $z \in H$ for which $H^1(U_z, F|_U)$ for a certain coherent ${\mathcal O}_X$-sheaf $F$ vanishes? Are they a reasonable algebro-geometric subset (closed subset or constructible subset or countable union of reasonable subsets)?
I tried to find existing research to this problem and also asked ChatGPT (not about the problem, but about links to math articles pertaining to it), but could not find much.
One thing I found a reference for is that for $Y = \mathrm{supp}\ D$ and $D$ an effective divisor on $X$ then there are cases where $X - Y$ is affine, but $D$ not ample (if $D$ is ample then $X - \mathrm{supp}\ D$ is of course affine).
Is this an uninteresting question or is it simply too difficult and intractable by the current means of algebraic geometry?

One thing to note is that if $X$ is normal and (geometrically) irreducible, then the codimension of $Y$ in $X$ must be $1$. Indeed, if the codimension of $Y$ is at least $2$, then the restriction map $k = \mathcal{O}(X)\rightarrow \mathcal{O}(U)$ is an isomorphism, so $U$ cannot be affine.
